# How to identify probing in the c-lightning implementation of the Lightning Network?

Tags: lightning-network, core-lightning, lightning-routing

I'm currently looking at output from the c-lightning -listforwards command.

A large portion of the payments are classified as local_failed with the failcode "4103 WIRE_TEMPORARY_CHANNEL_FAILURE".

Is it possible that some of the local fails are probing payments addressed to the node for which you don't have the secret key (obviously)? Or would a "payment" like that not show up in the -listforwards output?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot dissociate probing from a legitimate failed payment attempt. If you could, then you could just prevent it in the first place.

To expand a bit more:

> the node for which you don't have the secret key (obviously)?

There is no secret key. There is a payment preimage, the preimage to the hash used in the forwarded HTLC.

> Is it possible that some of the local fails are probing payments addressed to the node [...]?

If by "the node" you are referring to your node, no. It would be `WIRE_INCORRECT_OR_UNKNOWN_PAYMENT_DETAILS`.

If you are referring to the next node, it might. According to the protocol it must send an `incorrect_or_unknown_payment_details` error. But you wouldn't be able to tell them if they didn't respect the protocol, and instead sent a `temporary_channel_failure`.